# How to enable DRI for i915 laptop video card when glxgears not render output without error provided?

Tags: 20.04, video, intel-graphics, gpu-driver, i915

I've did

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel  libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo update-alternatives --remove gl_conf /usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf
```

I've also blacklisted nouveau driver

```
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf                                               

blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

But when i try to run glxgears it renders nothing(black screen).

```
$ vblank_mode=0 glxgears
ATTENTION: default value of option vblank_mode overridden by environment.
```

Errors in xorg log:

```
grep "EE" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   274.620] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   274.623] (EE) AIGLX error: dlopen of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
[   274.623] (EE) AIGLX error: unable to load driver i965
```

Comment: Do you have hybrid graphics (Intel+Nvidia)? If so you WANT the Nvidia graphics drivers.

Comment: No. I need intel.

Comment: That was NOT the question. If you have hybrid graphics then you need to install Nvidia drivers and then use Nvidia X Server settings to toggle graphics. Or use prime in command line. Removing the Nvidia drivers and on top of that even blacklisting nouveau is a dumb move and solves absolutely NOTHING about the Intel iGPU.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

This util is present in ubuntu fresh install.

Next package must be installed.

```
 i A libgl1-mesa-dri - free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
```